# SAXON 10 datetime is always processed as string despite having a date time variable

Tags: xpath, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

Recently I have migrated to Saxon 10 (XSLT 3.1) from Saxon 9 (XSLT 2.0). I have a variable $datetime Variable, that is of the type *DateTime* and whenever I have used the variable in XPATH expression calculator in my java application I have just used directly the variable and it used to get processed as the said variable type.

However, with Saxon 10 (XSLT 3.1), this variable during evaluation is always process as string type. I read the documentation where AtomicValue is made non-serializable in Saxon 10.5 hence, it is processed as string type.

I found a workaround that if I typecast the variable as `xs:datetime($datetime)` then the expression gets evaluated.

The current expression for reference is as follows:

```
current-dateTime() - $datetime
```

and the error I get is

```
Unsuitable types for- operation (xs:dateTimestamp, xs:string)
```

so here the second param is considered as string by saxon processor.

**Reference code**

*XSDateTimeDummyProperty.java*

```
public class XSDateTimeDummyProperty extends SaxonParentProperty<DateTimeValue> {


public static <T> T completeCopy(T orig) {
    if (orig == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        // Convert orig to stream obj and copy 
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static <T> T normalCopy(T orig) {
    if (orig == null) {
        return null;
    }
    T copiedRef = orig;
    return (T) copiedRef;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    XSDateTimeDummyProperty originalArgument = new XSDateTimeDummyProperty();

    originalArgument.setValue("2020-07-01T11:44:10.011705+02:30"); //dummyDATETIME-String
    XSDateTimeDummyProperty deepCopiedReference = XSDateTimeDummyProperty.completeCopy(originalArgument); // java.io.NotSerializableException occurs
    XSDateTimeDummyProperty normalCopiedReference = XSDateTimeDummyProperty.normalCopy(originalArgument);

    System.out.println(deepCopiedReference);
    System.out.println(normalCopiedReference);
}}
```

*SaxonParentProperty.java*

```
public abstract class SaxonParentProperty<T extends AtomicValue> {
T obj;
protected void setValue(Object value) {
    ConversionResult conversionResult = DateTimeValue.makeDateTimeValue((CharSequence) value, ConversionRules.DEFAULT);

    this.obj = (T) conversionResult;
}}
```

**Error At Runtime:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.xxx.utils.property.type.XSDateTimeDummyProperty
at com.xxx.utils.property.type.XSDateTimeDummyProperty.completeCopy(XSDateTimeDummyProperty.java:28)
```

It would be really helpful if I get an appropriate answer quickly.

Tried looking at the saxon documentation with little or less info.

Comment: Please provide a (short) way to reproduce the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: P.S. If `xs:datetime($datetime)` works in an expression, but `$datetime` does not, then `$datetime` is not of type `xs:dateTime`.  You can test this using the `instance of` operator: https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-instance-of

Comment: Do you use Saxon from the command line and pass the parameter from the command line? Then show us exactly how you do that. If you use Java code, show the relevant code.

Comment: PP.S. Please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/17153010

Comment: I'm afraid your question is very confusing. It's not clear whether you are talking about XPath variables or Java variables. Please show us code we can execute to illustrate the problem. The error message certainly means that $datetime is a string, but we can't tell why without more information. I've no idea what `XSDateProperty` etc have to do with it: I don't even recognise these names.

Comment: Hello @MichaelKay, XSDateProperty etc is our java class that use DateValue, DateTimeValue and TimeValue from the net.sf.saxon.value package. however, AtomicValue is made non-serializable in Saxon 10.5, Since all these Value classes extend AtomicValue which is now not serializable, my variables are not transformed/processed properly by saxon for the xpath variables.

Comment: Hello @MartinHonnen,
I use a Java/JavaSwing application, where there is a dialog called XPATH assistant, where It evaluates my XPATH expressions. Using SAXON 9 and XPATH version 2.0, the expression is evaluated smoothly, however for SAXON 10 and XPATH version 3.1, the expression gives the above error.

Comment: Hello @michael.hor257k,
I appreciate your quick response, but however I am working on a time bound customer task, I need to resolve the query quickly and I am relatively new to stack overflow community. Quick way to reproduce the issue would be to have that expression in any XPATH expression evaluator I guess.

Comment: The official API for Saxon is the s9api, you can find an XPath evaluation with a variable example in https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_10_9/entry/src/samples/java/he/S9APIExamples.java#L845. Overview of that API in https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.html.

Comment: MartinHonnen thank you I'll check the links that you provided.
@michael.hor257k I apologize, I never meant to be rude or waste your precious time in any manner, due to company policies, I cannot show you the complete screenshot of the evaluation. However, there are workflows and the value for $datetime can come from a number of ways like from database, or read from file or external system, and is of type xs:datetime eg. _2001-01-01T10:11:12.13+01:00_.

Comment: @SiddhantK. It doesn't matter **from** where the value comes from. What matters is **how** is it passed to the XSLT stylesheet (assuming you are talking about XSLT; at this point we cannot be sure even about that). If you are not allowed to explain how that's done, then we are not able to reproduce the problem - and without that it is not possible to provide an informed answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that up to Saxon 9.3 or so (that is, about 10 years ago) the AtomicValue class implemented Serializable, and I can conceive of applications that might be affected by the fact that we changed it. I find it a little surprising that it should have the symptoms you describe, but if you showed us some code I guess we could work it out, and advise you what changes to make to restore the previous behaviour.

### Later (16 Aug 2023)

If I recall correctly, the reason we made the change was that (a) we changed the internal implementation of some atomic values to use JDK classes that were not serialisable -- possibly something related to locales and timezones -- and (b) the original Saxon feature that required values to be serializable, namely the ability to serialize a compiled stylesheet in its entirety, had been dropped many years earlier.

You seem to be relying on serializability to make a deep copy of an atomic value. It shouldn't be necessary to make a deep copy, because atomic values are (for practical purposes) immutable. (The only exception is the `setTypeLabel()` method, but that is only called during initialization). If you really do need to make a copy, you can achieve this using:

```
AtomicValue x = ...
AtomicValue y = x.copyAsSubType(x.getItemType());
```

Comment: Hello @MichaelKay, I've added a small dummy code block in the description. The CompleteCopy generally takes in a serializable object and does a complete copy of all the properties of the object, which in my project is used extensively and cannot be altered. Hence for creating new references of the object we need this method. But after SAXON 10 update, I am unable to use this method since AtomicValue was made not serializable. In my sample here, I am just trying to access the copy method to show you the error. Please suggest me the changes such that my issue would hopefully resolve. Thank you.